# Angular using Jhipster, How to add or bundle external js files?

Tags: angular, angular6, jhipster

I want to add external js files to my angular app generated by jhipster.
Usually with angular-cli i do these and it works :

```
   "scripts": [
  "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf.js",
  "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf.worker.js",
  "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/viewer.js"
]
```

but in an angular-app generated using Jhipster, i canit found where i should put these code.

same thing for  "assets" and  "styles"

any ideas ?

Comment: add them in a custom  js folder in assets folder and give the link in angular.json

Comment: not working for me